# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED when making https request on same server running nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

Since a recent Plesk update on my server I been having issues with my nodejs apps making requests to api urls hosted on the same server and a bit lost as to whats causing it as they use to run fine. The api domain in question is still serving the site using apache but when my nodejs app makes a request to the site using https I get the error

{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }

however loading the same url in my browser loads fine.

Comment: I had same issue while back , figured out i was behind a corporate proxy , so had to use 
var options={
    hostname:'172.25.66.1',
    port:8080
}
and try changing http or https or ip directly. 
may help , not sure

Comment: Actually I believe the issue is something to do with it being a https request as doing the same request using http works fine.